# redirect doesnt save error

Tags: vimscript

Errors, ie python errors, appear in `:messages`. And yet, they are not present in the file generate by `redir >> fil`.

I wish they would be added too. Any chance?

For example, these lines aren't present in the file. But do appear in messages. (I did `py3 asfsafsd`)
[image]

Comment: What kind of Python errors? Can you suggest a reproducer? Does the message get displayed to the user as well, or only goes to the message buffer? `:redir` captures the output that the user sees, which might be somewhat different from what goes to messages...

Comment: added. It is nvim btw.

Comment: Downvote for giving a screenshot (not searchable) instead of pasting the text (searchable).

Comment: well, it is in red. It helps clarify the context. And I don't expect anyone to search this.